# WSO2 EMM 2.0 not installed correctly when Building from Source

Tags: wso2, soa, wso2-iot

Wso2 EMM 2.0 building from source ,
reference link https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM200/Building+from+Source#BuildingfromSource-Downloadingthesource

Device and Policy management (Core functionality) - https://github.com/wso2/carbon-device-mgt (MASTER Branch)

Plugins specific device management (Eg : Android, Windows) - https://github.com/wso2/carbon-device-mgt-plugins  (MASTER Branch)

EMM product repo - https://github.com/wso2/product-mdm  (MASTER Branch)

successfully build the product , the EMM 2.0 found `<EMM_SOURCE_HOME>/modules/distribution/target` directory, as `wso2mdm-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.zip`. when i extract and started the server ,server started but when i try to access

Publisher -localhost:9443/publisher/ not able to access the publisher ,
when i try to access Store - localhost:9443/store/ not able to access store but it redirects to publiser url .

Comment: Better if you specify the branch also!

Comment: @AbimaranKugathasan MASTER branch,

Comment: @AbimaranKugathasan can you please help me  ?

Answer (score 0):

Usually master branch is the place the current developments are being committed. So there could be a chance to have bugs which could affect to application functionality. Anyway if you need to build specific version of product from the source, it is better to checkout relevant tag first and build the tag. In your case it is https://github.com/wso2/product-emm/tree/v2.0.0

Also to build product from source, you don't need to build entire list of depended repositories (i.e carbon-device-mgt, carbon-device-mgt-plugins) unless you are going to build the product based on modified code, which is not in master branch or tags. Because WSO2 has nexus repository hosted and it has all required dependencies, which is needed to build the product. However if you would like to build product based on another branch of a depended repository, then you need to build the relevant branches of those depended repositories.

Thanks